# Is there a way to fill a specific column based on another column, n times?

Tags: mysql

11
22
33

```
I want the following result for my assign_item table :
```

ID ITEM_TYPE ITEM_ID PORTFOLIO_ID USER_ID
1  RESOURCE    11        1          1
2  RESOURCE    22        1          1
3  RESOURCE    33        1          1
4  RESOURCE    11        2          2
5  RESOURCE    22        2          2
6  RESOURCE    33        2          2

```
is there a way to accomplish that in sql ?
```

Comment: I am guessing `INSERT INTO t(ITEM_TYPE, ITEM_ID, USER_ID) SELECT 'RESOURCE', resource.id, user.user_id FROM user CROSS JOIN resource` should work.

Comment: You need to provide all three table description, with some data for testing purpose. The data should automatically updated on your `assign_item` table. If so you need a trigger